# Django, trouble deleting a record?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a Django class-based delete view

It is called by a template (DetailsView, which has a button on the bottom which i want to be able to click in order to delete the record)

The code in the template is this:

```
<div>
  <a href="{% url 'update_candidate' object.pk %}" class="button">Edit</a>
</div>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_candidate' object.pk %}" class="inline">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="object_pk" value="{{ object.pk}}">
  <button type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" class="link-button">
  </button>
</form>
```

The update_candidate works  using the object.pk... a page is displayed with the right object, but if i try and delete i get error

> Request Method:   POST Request URL:
>     http://127.0.0.1:8000/candidates/delete_candidate/1/ Django Version:
>     2.0.6 Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured Exception Value:  DeleteCandidateView is missing a QuerySet. Define
>   DeleteCandidateView.model, DeleteCandidateView.queryset, or override
>   DeleteCandidateView.get_queryset().
>
> POST Variable                     Value object_pk                     '1'
>   csrfmiddlewaretoken
>   'Vp3McmK88riynpBJ9U2yPRXNvI3i8ufeepY2FnRt1cktW7aw48p7JsYTnFWvk4kD'
>
> delete                       'delete'

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Message says that some of the views using a generic CBV [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) or a [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/flattened-index/#deleteview) has the wrong setup, in this case probably DeleteCandidateView is missing some of the following required attributes:

- `model`,
- `queryset`,

or you need to override `DeleteCandidateView.get_queryset`

---

It depends on the Generic Class Based View you are using, but it will tipically look like:

```
class DeleteCandidateView(DetailView):

    model = DeleteCandidate # or whatever your model is called
```

Comment: Thanks, i found my error, it was due to my model...i had Model = rather than model = . I expected django to throw an error. Got to be more careful in future.